# How can a working professional getting into a new field

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, application, undergraduate

I have EE major and CS minor in my bachelor degree (overseas, GPA ~3.7) and a CS master degree (US, rank about 30 in CS, GPA ~3.5). I've worked in tech industry for 9 years as a technical staff, but I don't have any publication or patten. I got a green card and have sufficient saving.

I'm thinking about getting into pure math. Although in my undergraduate years, I learned calculus, linear algebra, some engineering math, complex analysis, but the strengths are not comparable.

I see little chance of getting into a good math Phd program due to my thin and outdated profile. Redoing the whole bachelor degree seems impossible in terms of time and finance. Is there a way to strengthen my profile? Is there an "intermediate" program to learn just the mathematical knowledge and bridge me? I see some "Post-Baccalaureate Program" but they're not for mathematics. I'm willing to go abroad if the school is good and I'm accepted.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you wouldn't just apply for a PhD program and see if you succeed.

Comment: Your math background isn't outdated, but it is very thin. If you are near some university, or even a liberal arts college, see if you can take individual courses for credit. Talk to a department head, for example.

Comment: Getting a second masters in the related field that allows you to count work you’ve already could be an option.